# editing text with button value then storing in array to compare answers

Tags: jquery, arrays

http://jsfiddle.net/Victoriamisu/jKvvU/

The user will see a given n number of letters, let's say two, then will be shown the screen in the fiddle and click on the two letters they saw.

let's say the array of letters shown first is

```
var letters = new Array();
            letters = [
                { seq:  1, correct: 'C', display:"C", response:" "},
                { seq:  2, correct: 'X',  display:"X", response:" "}

            ];
```

I want it so that when the user clicks on one of the buttons, say she clicks on C, it will print C into the first box and then whatever he/she chooses next into the next box on the right in the fiddle.

After that, clicking the enter button will show a new screen comparing the answer against the correct ones. So .response will update and be compared to .correct.

I can load a new screen in my screen array, but how do I do it so that the value of each button is stored in response?

I was thinking something like

```
if( screens[curScreen].lettershow )   // I have the screen set so that it's lettershow:true
                {

            var responseRaw = new String;

            letters[curTrial].response = responseRaw;
```

and somehow make it show that responseRaw = $("#C").val();  (not sure if val is correct, and C is just the button id for any of those buttons)

The text on this screen will say 
either
correct: you answered _ _ (whatever the user clicked) or incorrect, with the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your jsfiddle so that the letters that the user clicks are added to the right hand panel.  http://jsfiddle.net/jKvvU/5/

I used the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btnControlLeft").on("click", function() {
        var letterbox = 1;
        while (letterbox < 7 && $("#" + letterbox).html() != "&nbsp;") {
            letterbox++;
        }

        if (letterbox < 7) {
            $("#" + letterbox).html($(this).attr("id"));
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: *for the letter display portion :)