# jquery storing button press value in array to compare to correct answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, storage

Reference [editing text with button value then storing in array to compare answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199081/editing-text-with-button-value-then-storing-in-array-to-compare-answers)

@user1333371 updated my fiddle to this: http://jsfiddle.net/jKvvU/5/ and it works fantastically in terms of changing the blank squares on the right to show the letters of the pressed buttons.

What I can't get correctly is taking these values and storing the values and then comparing them with the correct answer.

My array will look something like this

```
var letters = new Array();
            letters = [
                { seq:  1, correct: 'C', display:"C", response:" "},
                { seq:  2, correct: 'X',  display:"X", response:" "}

            ];
```

So I was thinking of doing something like

```
 if (letters.response == letters.correct)
```

But I'm not sure how to initially even store the data...

What will happen is if all the answers are correct, so all two are pressed correctly, then upon hitting enter a screen, div, whatever will show up saying yes you got it right then print the user's answers. but if just one is incorrect then the screen will print those answers as well.

Or maybe there's another way to do it without the response:" " part?

Comment: What kind of 'storage' solution are looking for? Will `localStorage` work?

Comment: Well I want it so that it can update the response portion in letters[] , at least I think that would be a solution... or make some sort of array, then compare those stored answers with the values of .correct in letters[]. The answers would be the letters of teh pressed buttons in the fiddle

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but I made a fiddle that could help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3sT2/

Comment: Actually this looks like something I can definitely use/change around to do what I need! Thank you! However, I'm trying to make it so that instead of evaluating the response after one buttonpress, pressing enter will wait until both buttons are pressed (C and X) and then say correct of incorrect.

Comment: Ah...I think abetter way to explain it is it is like a quiz. So it isn't "scored," at least the user doesn't know it's scored, until the enter button is pressed, which happens after the user chooses two answers.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle and added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update the Fiddle to reflect what you're trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/Udubg/4/

Once again this probably isn't the perfect solution, but it will give you an idea about how to structure what you're trying to make.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

           var correct  = [ 'C', 'X' ]
           ,   response = [];

$(".btnControlLeft").on( "click", function() {

    var letterbox = 1;
    while (letterbox < 7 && $("#" + letterbox).html() != "&nbsp;") {
        letterbox++;
    }

    if (letterbox < 7) {

        console.log("update " + letterbox);

       var letter = $( this ).attr( "id" );

        $("#" + letterbox ).html( letter );

        response.push( letter );

    }

});

$( '.btnControlEnter' ).on( 'click', function( e ){

    e.preventDefault();

    $.each( correct, function( index , value ){ 

          if( value === response[ index ] ) {

              console.log( 'Correct!',  response[ index ]  );

            } else{

             console.log( 'Wrong', response[ index ] );

            }   
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This structure is what I was looking to do!